# Many to Many raw query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got 3 tables `posts`, `tags`, and `posts_tags`.

```
posts:
 - id
 - title

tags: 
- id
- text

posts_tags:
- id
- post_id
- tag_id
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the posts that have a tag with an id of 1.

my query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN posts_tags ON posts_tags.tag_id = 1;
```

This is returning all of my posts even the one with different tag ids and not just the post with a tag id of 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding to all tags, not to a limited subset. Put `tag_id = 1` into a "where" clause and join with a specific match:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts p 
-- You don't care about non-matches, so use an inner join to automatically filter those
INNER JOIN posts_tags pt 
  -- JOIN looks for times when this condition evaluates to true
  -- If I just test for tag_id = 1, if it's true for one tag, it's true for all posts. 
  -- Instead, I look for places where the two tables match up.
  ON p.id = pt.post_id
WHERE pt.tag_id = 1
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have post IDs in the posts_tags post_id column?

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment before I saw you answered it. I had made a mistake on my end this query is exactly what I'm looking for thank you